# Segmentation Default (Double Pointer/structs)

Tags: c

I'm having a segmentation fault on the following code. It's a C project for the university. The purpose of this code is to read data from an input file, and place it into a 2D array created with a double pointer. In other words, in the first "for cycle" I will read 3 integers: the row, the column and the value. For example, 3 3 2, is row 3, column 3, value 2.

```
void cria_mapa(FILE *InputFile1, FILE *OutputFile, labirinto_struct *labirinto){

   int i=0, k=0;
   int linha,coluna,valor=0;

   labirinto->map = (int **) malloc(labirinto->num_linhas*sizeof(int *));

   if( labirinto-> map == NULL){
        exit(0);
    }

     for(i=0;i<labirinto->num_linhas;i++){
     labirinto->map[i] = (int *) calloc(labirinto->num_colunas, sizeof(int));
   }

    for(k=0;k<labirinto->num_paredes;k++){
       if(fscanf(InputFile1, "%d %d %d", &linha, &coluna, &valor)!=3){
            exit(0);
       }

       labirinto->map[linha][coluna]=valor;

       fprintf(OutputFile, "%d %d %d\n", linha, coluna, labirinto->map[linha][coluna]);

   }
   return;
}
```

and I have a struct:

```
typedef struct _labirinto_struct
{
    int num_linhas, num_colunas, num_paredes;
    int Pxi, Pyi, Px2, Py2;
    char letra;
    int variante;
    int **map;   

}labirinto_struct;
```

```
void free_mapa(labirinto_struct *labirinto){

    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<labirinto->num_linhas;i++){
     free(labirinto->map[i]);
   }


    free(labirinto->map);

   return;

}
```

Comment: Do you have a backtrace? On what line are you getting the segfault?

Comment: Has `labirinto` (the last parameter in the function call) been properly initialized before calling `cria_mapa`?

Comment: @Locke I think it's in this instruction ```labirinto->map[linha][coluna]=valor;```

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I initialized the structure and everything seems fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code, allocations and deallocations, looks good so far.

But you should check the values read:

```
if (fscanf(InputFile1, "%d %d %d", &linha, &coluna, &valor)!=3) {
    exit(0);
}

if (linha >= labirinto->num_linhas) {
    fprintf(stderr, "linha overflow: %d vs %d\n", linha, labirinto->num_linhas);
    exit(1);
}

if (coluna >= labirinto->num_colunas) {
    fprintf(stderr, " overflow: %d vs %d\n", coluna, labirinto->num_colunas);
    exit(1);
}

labirinto->map[linha][coluna]=valor;
```

I would guess, that the lines and columns given start at `1` up to `max` and not `0` to `max - 1`.

Comment: I did what you suggested. When I run the program, this appears: Overflow 10 vs 10. Does this mean I'm using more than what I've allocated? what should i change

Comment: This means, the program tries to access entries beyond the allocated memory. When you write outside the allocated memory, memory structures will become corrupted and segfault eventually.

Comment: Problem solved! What i did was change the code: ```labirinto->map[linha-1][coluna-1] = valor```. Thank you very much for the help! Now works without errors